# Tableau data extract refresh from Google BigQuery takes very long

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

We are very pleased with the combination BigQuery <-> Tableau Server with **live connection**. However, we now want to work with a **data extract** (500MB) on Tableau Server (since this datasource is not too big and is used very frequently). This takes **too much time to refresh** (1.5h+). We noticed that only 0.1% is query time and the rest is data export. Since the Tableau Server is on the same platform and location, latency should not be a problem.

This is similar to the slow export of a BigQuery table to a single file, which can be solved by using **"daisy chain"** option ([wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#exportingmultiple)). Unfortunately we can't use similar logic with a Google BigQuery data extract refresh in Tableau...

We have identified some approaches, but are not pleased with our current ideas:

1. Working with **incremental refresh**: our existing BigQuery table rows can change: these changes can only be applied in Tableau if you do a full refresh
2. Exporting the **BigQuery table to GCS** using the daisy chain option and making a Tableau data extract using the **[Tableau SDK](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_samples_python.htm%3FTocPath%3DTableau%2520SDK%2520Samples%7C_____1)**: this would result in quite some overhead...
3. Writing a **Dataflow job** using a custom sink for Tableau Server (data extracts).
4. Experimenting with a **Tableau web connector** that communicates directly with the BigQuery API: I don't think this will be faster? I didn't see anything about parallelizing calls with the Tableau web connecector, but I didn't try this approach yet.

We would prefer a non-technical option, to limit maintenance... Is there a way to modify the Tableau connector to make use of the "daisy chain" option for BigQuery?

Comment: BigQuery's biggest win is its speed and power at scale.  It can aggregate massive amounts of data within seconds.  Generally speaking, data extracts in Tableau when dealing with large datasets tend to be better suited for already aggregated data.  For best performance, the bulk of the query work has to be on the BigQuery side with Tableau serving more as a malleable front end.  Otherwise, you're using BQ more as data storage than a query engine.  As suggested by @Wouter, it may be best to build some custom queries and extract the results rather than extract the data and query from Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

You've uploaded the data in BigQuery. Can't you just use the input for that load job (a CSV perhaps) as input for Tableau?

When we use Tableau and BigQuery we also notice that extracts are slow but we generally don't do that because you lose BigQuery's power. We start with a live data connection at first, and then (if needed) convert this into a custom query that aggregates that data into a much smaller datasets which extracts in just a few seconds.

Another way to achieve higher performance with BigQuery and Tableau is aggregating or joining tables on beforehand. JOINs on huge tables can be slow, so if you use a lot of those you might consider generating a denormalised dataset which does all of the JOIN-ing first. You will get a dataset with a lot of duplicates and a lot of columns. But if you select only what you need in Tableau (hide unused fields!) then these columns won't count in your query cost.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately we have a lot of legacy dashboards that depend on the data being in one table (not the preferred approach of using multiple tables). Since we don't have the budget/time to remake the dashboards, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 1):

One recommendation I have seen is similar to your point 2 where you export the BQ table to Google Cloud Storage and then use the Tableau Extract API to create a .tde from the flat files in GCS.

This was from an article on the Google Cloud site so I'd assume it would be best practice:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/the-switch-to-self-service-marketing-analytics-at-zulily-best-practices-for-using-tableau-with-bigquery

There is an article here which provides a step by step guide to achieving the above.

https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-23161

It would be nice if Tableau optimised the BQ connector for extract refresh using the BigQuery Storage API. We too have our Tableau Server environment in the same GCP zone as our BQ datasets and experience slow refresh times.